# How do I create a list when using a has_and_belongs_to_many join table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm pretty new in rails so please be patient with my ignorance. I have two models: user and event. I've generated the migration that creates the join table events_users and I've declared has_and_belongs_to_many on both models. What I want to do generally is to create a list of users per event. I have a join method in my events controller that does the following:

```
def join
if current_user
    @events_users = Events_users.new
    @events_users.user = current_user
    @events_users.event = @event
    @events_users.save
    redirect_to events_url
else
    redirect_to new_user_session_url
end
end
```

In my routes.rb, I have this:

```
    match 'events/:id' => 'events#join', :as => :join
```

Basically, the method doesn't seem to work and my events_users table doesn't update. I need to know what I have to do when a user clicks 'Join' such that his/her id and the event id is added in the events_users table.

Comment: You mean to fetch the users of an event? Like `@event.users`? Adding is also easy, simply use: `@event.users += [user1, user2, ...]`

Comment: That's it? And the association is saved in events_users table?

Comment: Yes of course! :) This is the reason for this whole relation stuff. To use it simply. But don't forget to save the `@event`!

Comment: Let me know if it is working or not for you. If not working, provide more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify it to:

```
def join
  if current_user
    @event.users << current_user
    @event.save

    redirect_to events_url
  else
    redirect_to new_user_session_url
  end
end
```

Also, the addition in the `@event.users` can handle any array operations.

Comment: Hi, still not working. :( Is my routes.rb correct? I also have `<%= link_to button_to "Join", join_path(@event), confirm: 'Really join this?' %>` in my show.html.erb

Comment: You don't need both `link_to` and `button_to` only one of them.